# CSharp Prepared Statement with MySQL does not work

Tags: c#, mysql

*Hello folk, 
first I would like to tell you that I am new to CSharp and that is why I did not know that my way of creating the connection with MySQL was wrong, so because of that I had to change it with Prepared Statement. Please be kind!*

*THis is the method that I am trying to make it works.*

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidatesLogin (User eUser)
    {
        var Email = eUser.Email;
        var Password = eUser.Password;
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = MySqlConn.cmd;
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(" from User " + "WHERE Email=@email " + "AND Password=@password",
                    MySqlConn.conn);
                cmd.Prepare();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteReader();


            //encrypting the login user password 
            //the encrypter and decrypter must have same key which is 'kahat' below
            var encryptpassword = EncryptHelper.EncryptString(eUser.Password, "kahat");

            // Returns true when username and password match:
            if (result > 0)
            {
                System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(eUser.Email, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index", new { area = "Index" });

            }

            else
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Login failed. Email or password supplied doesn't exist.";
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ThrowJsonError(ex);
        }
    }
```

*And this code below is my actual connection which works very well.*

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Validate(User eUser)
        {
            try
            {
                //Pull email and password from login page
                var Email = eUser.Email;
                var Password = eUser.Password;

                //Pull first email and password from database
                var currentUser = this.rpGeneric.Find<User>(" from User WHERE Email=:email ", new string[] { "email" }, new object[] { Email }).FirstOrDefault();

                //encrypting the login user password 
                //the encrypter and decrypter must have same key which is 'kahat' below
                var encryptpassword = EncryptHelper.EncryptString(eUser.Password, "kahat");
                //Comparing user password in login page and current password in db
                if (currentUser != null && encryptpassword.Equals(currentUser.Password, StringComparison.Ordinal) && currentUser.EmailConfirmed == true)
                {
                    System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(eUser.Email, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Index", new { area = "Index" });
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Login failed. Email or password supplied doesn't exist.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ThrowJsonError(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Never store passwords in plain text in the database! Your question suggests you are doing this because you compare the users input directly with your query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text** or encrypt passwords, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `ehash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query is incomplete.

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand(" from User " + "WHERE Email=@email " + "AND Password=@password",
                MySqlConn.conn);
```

You aren't telling MySql what you want it to do, you need to add the "select " clause and the column names that you're selecting from the table:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("select [*],[column, column...] from User " + "WHERE Email=@email " + "AND Password=@password",
                MySqlConn.conn);
```

Comment: As an observation: you also don't need to concatenate your command string. `"select * from user where Email = @email and Password = @password` works just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers but also I cannot understand why the cmd here: MySqlCommand cmd = MySqlConn.cmd;   is underlined, it says object does not contain definition for cmd and no extension method cmd acception a first argument of type object

Comment: I'm not sure what code you're referring to since I can't see that in your post. What that error means is that you're trying to reference something that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like you are missing the `SELECT` clause in your query unless it's a typo as pointed below

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand(" from User " + "WHERE Email=@email " + "
                        ^... Here
```